# Upload files with FTP to Debian machine give 505 error

Tags: debian, vsftpd, filezilla

I'll upload a CMS to my Debian webserver. If I use FileZilla to upload the files I've got a 505 error. I've installed VSFTPD to the machine and I've set this things only once:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
write_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
```

After it I've restart the service with this command.

```
service vsftpd restart
```

My username and password are correct so that isn't the problem. I can also see the full file structure in FileZilla.

Comment: So you can connect to your FTP server, but attempting to upload a file fails, as if permissions on the directory did not allow writing?

Comment: can you please check logs, and paste here for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `vsftpd.conf` like this:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Save and restart the vsftpd service:

```
service vsftpd restart
```